# Is there a closed form CDF for the sum of two triangularly distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, triangular-distribution

To calculate the PDF of the sum of two triangularly distributed random variables all I did was add them together and divided by two:

$\dfrac{f(x, a1, b1, c1) + f(x, a2, b2, c2)}{2}$

[image]

And implementing it in Python gets me the following PDF:

[image]

My issue was with the CDF. Addition doesn't work, but I don't know how to mathematically derive a closed form for it:
[image]

Comment: Your proposed method for obtaining the pdf of the sum is incorrect. So it is not too surprising that the CDF that you find is deficient too.

Comment: Oh, I'm not too experienced with statistics. What is wrong with how I'm finding the PDF?

Comment: You added the two pdf functions together. That is what you do with a [mixture of variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). If that is what you intended with the sum of two variables, then it should work the same for the pdf. We can't see how you generated the CDF and it seems like a computation error.

Answer (score 4):

Following on @WindFish's answer, it is possible to derive the closed form solution, but it is very detailed.  For each $z$ you need to keep track of the regions of $x$ and $y$ to determine which part of the density you fall in.  To see this, draw lines of equal $z$ through the $xy$ plane.  Numerical integration can handle the multiple domains given a $z$ a little easier than writing out the analytical solution.

```r
require(triangle)

a1 <- 0
b1 <- 1
c1 <- 0.5
a2 <- 3
b2 <- 5
c2 <- 3

X <- triangle::rtriangle(10000, a1, b1, c1)
Y <- triangle::rtriangle(10000, a2, b2, c2)
Z <- X + Y

fz <- function(z) {
  integrand <- function(x, z) triangle::dtriangle(x, a1, b1, c1)*triangle::dtriangle(z-x, a2, b2, c2)
  sapply(z, function(z1){
    ifelse(z1 < a1 + a2, 0, 
           ifelse(z1 > b1 + b2, 0,
                  integrate(integrand, lower = a1, upper = b1, z = z1)$value))
  })
}

z <- seq(a1+a2-0.5, b1+b2+0.5, length = 100)
dz <- fz(z)

hist(Z, freq = FALSE, breaks = 30, xlim = range(z), main = "")
lines(z, dz, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a Fourier convolution.
For x distributed according to g(x), and y distribution according to h(y), the pdf of z=x+y is given by the attached image.
(Side note for product of variables z=x*y, you would need to do a Mellin convolution).

[image: Fourier Convolution]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the probability density function $$\dfrac{f(x, a1, b1, c1) + f(x, a2, b2, c2)}{2}$$ then the cumulative distribution function will be $$\dfrac{F(x, a1, b1, c1) + F(x, a2, b2, c2)}{2}$$

We can't see how you generated the CDF in your image and it seems like a computation error.

---

Sidenote: You added the two pdf functions together. That is what you do with a [mixture of variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). This is not what you do to compute a sum of two random variables, for a sum of random variables you use convolution.